# Google Sheets custom menu pass a variable to function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm following the solution found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46529007/can-a-google-sheets-custom-menu-pass-a-variable-to-function) but when I click one of the generated buttons, I get this error:
Script function not found: test1.

```
const flags = {};
flags["test1"] = "data";
flags["test2"] = "data";

function onOpen(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  Object.keys(flags).forEach(function (flag) {
    this[flag] = function () {
      addToFlagInteract(flag);
    }
  });

  var flagMenu = ui.createMenu('Flag');
  var flagSubMenu = ui.createMenu('Add to Flag');

  Object.keys(flags).forEach(function (flag) {
    flagSubMenu.addItem(flag,flag);
  });

  flagMenu.addSubMenu(flagSubMenu).addToUi();
}

function addToFlagInteract(flag){
  //Do something
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64384141/) answer your question and explain Tanaike's answer?

Comment: @TheMaster From your comment, I noticed that I forgot [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64383424/7108653). I think that this question is the same as it. So, I deleted my answer. Because I think that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64383424/7108653) can explain the OP's issue well.

Comment: @Tanaike No need to delete. It may be helpful even if we close this as duplicate. In your answer though, a minor issue would be `onOpen` would run twice, when onOpen is triggered, right? Also, I think OP missed the part where you added `onOpen()` at the end.

Comment: @TheMaster Yes. I think so. When I had searched the duplicated question when I saw this question, unfortunately, I couldn't find it. About `run twice`, for example, when in order to run `onOpen` as the global, `const sample = (_ => onOpen())()` is put to the script editor, when the Spreadsheet is opened, `sample` and `onOpen` are run in order. So, I proposed to put `onOpen()` as the global. And, thank you for editing. I reopened it.

Comment: @Tanaike But `onOpen` is run twice right? **When spreadsheet is opened**, first `sample` is run -> During `sample` run, `onOpen()` is run once -> Globals are loaded and now, `onOpen()` is run again as a trigger.  PS: Feel free to revert my edits as you see fit.

Comment: @TheMaster I think that you are correct. In the case that a line of `onOpen();` and a line of `const sample = (_ => onOpen())()` are put , both situations are the same. When Spreadsheet is opened, the function put as the global is run, and then, `function onOpen(){}` is run. By this flow, I think that `onOpen` is run 2 times. When `onOpen` is installed as the installable trigger, `onOpen` is run 4 times. When OP don't want to run 2 times when Spreadsheet is opened, for example, `function onOpen(e) {if (e) return; do something }` and `onOpen();` is used, `onOpen` is run only one time.

Answer (score 1):

- I think that in your script when the function is run with the custom menu, the functions of `test1` and `test2` are not installed.
- By executing `onOpen()` as the global, when the function of `test1` is run from the custom menu, `onOpen()` is run. By this, the function `test1` is installed and that function can be run.

#### Modified script:

```js
//Same globals 
function onOpen(){
  //Same script in original post
}

function addToFlagInteract(flag){
  //Do something
}

onOpen(); // <--- Added
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "installed". Additionally, onOpen is a global function and I can confirm that the functions test1 and test2 are also global functions by checking the debugger.

Comment: @DrDaNkk Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I think that in your `onOpen`, the functions of `test1` and `test2` are created and put to `this` of Google Apps Script. But in your script, when `test1` is run from custom menu, the function `test1` is not put. By this, such error occurs. So I proposed above modification. By the way, I cannot understand `Additionally, onOpen is a global function and I can confirm that the functions test1 and test2 are also global functions by checking the debugger.`, can I ask you about the detail of it?