# Functions for individual items within a menu

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created multiple items within a sub menu, making it a dynamic sub menu. I however don't know any way in order to differentiate between the different items once they've been clicked. Anyone got any ideas?

```js
warSubMenu.addItem(chosenMenu,'loadLoadout(' + chosenMenu +')');
```

Above is the code I've used in order to create the sub menu.
I've tried to pass an argument through the function `loadLoadout()` however `.addItem()` believes the the function to be entirely separate rather than an argument being passed into `loadLoadout()`.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a [mcve] including if you plan to share this spreadsheet and how the function that creates the menu will be called. Also add the textual error message.

Comment: By the way, also you should add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask]. Related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31539911/1595451, https://stackoverflow.com/q/64383424/1595451

Comment: You can execute functions by function name.  So you can build a dynamic menu in html based upon a select tag selected item's name

Comment: the ui menu methods do not support arguments atm, you need to think of some work arounds.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that script is passing a string that is not a valid function name. A function name should not contain parenthesis.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu#additemcaption,-functionname

Related

- [What characters are valid for JavaScript variable names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1661197/1595451)
- [Google Apps Script: Dynamically creating spreadsheet menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31539911/1595451)
- [Can a Google Sheets custom menu pass a variable to function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46529007/1595451)
- [Set anonymous/dynamic functions to Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64383424/1595451)